# Generate SerialVersionUID for Kotlin classes in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

On Intellij, how would you be able to generate a SerialVersionUID for classes that are written in Kotlin?

I've enabled the inspection in Intellij that does this:

> Reports any Serializable classes which do not provide a serialVersionUID field. Without a serialVersionUID field, any change to a class will make previously serialized versions unreadable.

But this only works with Java classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. This inspection does not work for Kotlin classes. Maybe you could file an issue to Jetbrains so that they could fix it.

For generation of SerialVersionUID you can use JDK's build-in command [serialver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/serialver.html).

> E:\workspace\target\classes>serialver Address
>
> Address:    static final long serialVersionUID = -687991492884005033L;

Other usage [examples](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/using-serialver-command-examples).

Comment: Thanks for the serialver suggestion. I'll file a issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't found such issue in Kotlin's youtrack, so please create it.

If you use Idea, you can create Live Template for this purpose.

Valid `serialVersionUID` should looks like:

```
class Test : Serializable {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic private val serialVersionUID = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be generated with plugins!

I just released a plugin, [click here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13497-generateserialversionuid) to download and install, or search `GenerateSerialVersionUID` in IDEA/Android Studio to find the installation whose author is `Ouyangfeng`. If you don't know how to use it, please click here: https://github.com/yuanhoujun/intellij-generate-serial-version-uid-plugin.

If you encounter any problems during use, please submit issues on Github, appreciate it